# Any tool that can confirm if a drive with raw partition is part of a ZFS pool?

Tags: macos, windows-10, partition, zfs

I have a client issue that I am working on with a stack of SSD drives and a machine that they were previously installed in.  As of now, the stack of drives shows up in a few Operating Systems (Win10, Win7, Mac OSX) as an unpartitioned raw space.  I am looking for a simple way to examine the drive and see if it is actually raw, or just formatted for ZFS.

Does anyone know of a Windows or Mac Utility that could help?  I've tried a few recovery software programs, that hinted at being compatible with ZFS formatted drives, but have yet to see anything that would indicate if it was actually a ZFS, or simply not formatted.

Regards,

Ed

Answer (score 3):

ZFS is storing at the start and at the end of each device a magic number, **0x00bab10c** ("oobabloc", i.e. überblock), reversed for little-endian: **0x0cb1ba00**.

So if this number doesn't appear in the device data, you can be sure it isn't used by ZFS. If it does appear, you need to investigate a little further.

For details, have a look to the ZFS on disk specification draft available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324061942/http://maczfs.googlecode.com/files/ZFSOnDiskFormat.pdf), especially page 13.

Comment: Awesome information.  Thank you!  I appreciate the link too!